# Does there exist positive numbers $a, b$, $b>a$, such that $a/n > b/(n+1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $n = 1, \ldots, \infty$ be a natural number.

Does there exist $a, b$, with the condition $b>a$, such that $$\frac an > \frac{b}{(n+1)}$$ for all $n$?

Furthermore, does there exist $a,b$ with the condition $b > a$ such that $$\frac{a}{n^c} > \frac{b}{(n+1)^c}$$ for all $n$ and some $c \in (0, 1]$?

---

Attempt:

We want: $\frac a1 > \frac b2, \frac a2 > \frac b3, \frac a3 > \frac b4$...

From the first inequality, we want $a > b/2$, so let $a = 1.1b/2$, but $1.1b/4 < \frac b3$ so the second inequality fails...., so we change $a = 1.5b/2$, but the third inequality fails....

Comment: $a/n > b/(n+1) \implies \frac{a}{b-a} >n \implies a >n$, so will fail for any $n \ge a$

Comment: @Henry Thank you, that was obvious. I guess my question is for a given $c \in (0, 1]$ can we find such $a,b$

Comment: In this case just power your inequality to $1/c$ and repeat the same argument as Henry , just replacing $a$ by $a^{1/c}$ and $b$ by $b^{1/c}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a/n^c > b/(n+1)^c $

$ \implies (n+1)^c/n^c > b/a $

$ \implies (n+1)/n > (b/a)^{1/c} $

$ \implies 1/n > (b/a)^{1/c}-1 $

$ \implies n < \frac{1}{(b/a)^{1/c}-1} =\frac{a^{1/c}}{b^{1/c}-a^{1/c}}$

so will fail with  $n \ge \frac{a^{1/c}}{b^{1/c}-a^{1/c}}$